# Can not convert from character to string

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms, messagebox

I want a message box to pop up displaying the first character of the string accepted from user via textbox and when the user clicks on ok button of message box, the next character pops up in the message box until null is reached.

I have created this program but because of obvious reasons its giving the following error:
"cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'"
please suggest some changes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace loop_Message
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str;
            str = stringTxt.Text;
            for (int i = 0; str[i] != null; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(str[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consder reading on difference between C# and C++  - one of the languages has 0 terminated strings, another does not.

Comment: Try this MessageBox.Show(str[i].ToString());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
foreach (char c in stringTxt.Text)
{
    MessageBox.Show(c.ToString());
}
```

[MessageBox.Show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/519bytz3.aspx) requires a `string` parameter, so you need to convert the character to a string.

Your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; str[i] != null; i++)
```

raises an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Strings in `.NET` are not character arrays like in `C`. They are actually null-terminated, but you cannot access the null character by using its index (which is equal to `Length`). CLR checks the index, and becuase it is out of the range of valid indexes for string (`0` to `Length-1`), throws an exception.

Answer (score 2):

`MessageBox.Show()` receives an string, and you're passing a `char` object. Do the following:

```
MessageBox.Show(str[i].ToString());
```

Comment: it gives this error: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'

Comment: what exactly is `stringTxt`? Please, provide the entire source code.

Comment: stringTxt is the name of the text box ,user is entering the string into.

Comment: Neither do I, which is why I came looking for help..
anyways thanks for trying.. I used the other method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line with this:

```
for (int i = 0; str[i] != null; i++)
{
   MessageBox.Show(str[i].ToString());
}
```

The `MessageBox.Show()` needs a string value but you are passing a character.